# How to Change the loaded environement in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, dotenv, phpdotenv

I have to `.env` files `.env.local` and `.env.pro` and I don't know how to switch between files, I tried  changing `config\app.php` from

```
'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'pro'),
```

to

```
'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'local'),
```

But I get a blank screen with no errors, How to tell  the framework which file has to load?

Comment: I think if you set the APP_ENV in the `.env` file it will try to load the `.env.{env}` file with additional values which will overwrite the ones set in `.env`

Comment: The reason you are having a blank page is probably because you have no file that are only ```.env```, try changing ```.env.local``` to ```.env```. Your local app should start again.

Comment: What you did in the ```config\app.php ``` is changing the default ```env``` value. It's a fallback in case your application can't find ```APP_ENV``` into your ```.env``` file. Now, why you want to perform env change within your app? The purpose of dotenv is to keep credential out of the code and out of subversion tools. Is your environment dynamically changing?

Answer (score 0):

The .env file should not be replicated from your DEV environment to your production environment, so you have different versions of these files in each environment.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/configuration#environment-configuration

If you're using git for version control the .env file is excluded by default. However, if you need to give hints to other developers about specific configurations needed you should can put them into the .env.example file. For testing you may as described in the article in the Laravel documentation use a specific .env file, ie.: .env.testing